# Send the selected option using get to another page

Tags: html, ajax

I have a dropdown select option.There is button.On clicking the button the selected option must be send to another page "update.php" so that i can access the option there.In my case the new page is not loading or getting redirected to.

```
<select id=31 >
  <option value="pending">pending</option>
  <option value="accepted">accepted</option>
  <option value="in progress">in progress</option>
  <option value="cant">Cant be done</option>
</select></td>
<td><button id=i31 onclick="$.get("update.php",{id:31,s:$("#31 option:selected").text();})" >Submit</button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `update.php` is in another directory than your HTML make sure to use the absolute path to the file.

If you want the whole page to redirect you will want to use:

```
<form action="update.php" method="POST">
    <select id="31" name="myFormOption" >
        <option value="pending">pending</option>
        <option value="accepted">accepted</option>
        <option value="in-progress">in progress</option>
        <option value="cant">Cant be done</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And in `update.php` catch the incoming POST with

```
if(isset($_POST['myFormOption'])) {
    //Process Form Here
}
```

If you have to use AJAX I would then use `window.location.href = "http://example.com";` after the call is successful.

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: Added AJAX Script

```
<script>
    $('#i31').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'update.php',
            data: { id: 31, s: $("#31 option:selected").val() },
            success: function() {
                window.location.href = "http://example.com";
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: is there a way without using forms ?

Comment: I added an AJAX script to my post. Let me know how that goes.